# React useState variable doesn't get copied by value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-state

I have a very basic example and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have a very simple counter and I want to copy its initial state to another variable without the reactivity but can't do so.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState({ val: 10 });
  const numberAssign = Object.assign({}, number);
  const numberJSON = { ...number };
  const numberSpread = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(number));
  const clicked = () => {
    setNumber({ val: number.val + 1 });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clicked}>Inc</button>
      <p>{number.val}</p>
      <p>{numberAssign.val}</p>
      <p>{numberJSON.val}</p>
      <p>{numberSpread.val}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

All of the variables get incremented when clicking the button but I want only the `number` variable to increment.

Comment: `useState` will always return the "latest" state value - that's the whole point of it. So don't assign that value to other variables if you don't want those variables to also get the updated value.

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve the value from it (without the reactivity part)?

Comment: each time you call setNumber the whole App function is called again with the updated number value. So all the code is evaluated again with the updated value. If you want to make a copy of the initialState you will need to use another hook for that to keep the value unchanged. For example you can check out useMemo hook

Comment: Ok, will check that out, thanks

Comment: or you can initialise number value outside of the component and use it in useState as initial value.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are not behaving abnormally. You are setting the variables to the value of the state variable which in this case is constantly being updated.
Try having the val variable declared outside of the state

```
`const val = 10;
const [number, setNumber] = useState({ val });`
```

then use val instead of the number state.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is going to help you a lot, but you can use another useState hook where you gonna store the prev value of the current state. Code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [currNum, setCurrNum] = useState(10);
  const [prevNum, setPrevNum] = useState(0);
  const clicked = () => {
    setPrevNum(prevNum);
    setCurrNum(prevNum+=1);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clicked}>Inc</button>
      <p>{currNum}</p>
      <p>{prevNum}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On every setState(useState) action the component will rerender everything inside it. It will only keep the values which created using react hooks such as useState (That is what useState wants to do)

Put a `console.log('rerender')` just before all useStates you will see it will trigger on its very action, that means in functional components it are will not keep any variables or values unless it is created using react hooks, even if it is const variable

In you case this const variables are created again and assigned new  number object to it that's why it is getting updated every time. but you can use it in different useStates, or you can define it inside a useEffect wich will trigger only calls in specific times
import { useState } from "react";

```
export default function App() {
  console.log('rerender')
  const [number, setNumber] = useState({ val: 10 });
  const [numberAssign, setN] = useState(Object.assign({}, number));
  const [numberJSON, setJSON] = useState({ ...number });
  const [numberSpread,setSpread] = useState(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(number)));
  const clicked = () => {
    setNumber({ val: number.val + 1 });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clicked}>Inc</button>
      <p>{number.val}</p>
      <p>{numberAssign.val}</p>
      <p>{numberJSON.val}</p>
      <p>{numberSpread.val}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand the full scope of your question, but i assume you're looking for the `useRef` hook

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

in your code, it would work like this:

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const currNumber = useRef({ val: 10 });
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(currNumber.current);
  const clicked = () => {
    setNumber({ val: number.val + 1 });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clicked}>Inc</button>
      <p>{number.val}</p>
      <p>{numberAssign.val}</p>
      <p>{numberJSON.val}</p>
      <p>{numberSpread.val}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this way, `currentNumber.current` will always keep 10, unless you change it...